# How order by works?

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying order some posts by meta_value (featured) and then by title. I'm getting the featured ones in a correct order, however, I got some non-featured mixed after the featured ones, I noticed that this happens only in the first page. Am I doing something wrong? What I need to do to get featured first and non-featured in an alphabeticall order?, this is my query(Using a premium theme called Vantage):

```
function appthemes_addon_on_top_query( $wp_query ){

    $addon_type = $wp_query->get( 'addon_on_top' );



    if( ! $addon_type || ! appthemes_addon_exists( $addon_type ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $addon_info = appthemes_get_addon_info( $addon_type );


    $flag_key   = $addon_info['flag_key']; // _listing-featured-cat
    $meta_query = (array) $wp_query->get( 'meta_value', 1 );

    $meta_query = array_filter( $meta_query );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => $flag_key,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'   => $flag_key,
                'value' => 1,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => $flag_key,
                'value'   => 1,
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
    );





    $wp_query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    /* Set an order by meta_value first and then by title */
    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'post_title' => 'ASC' ) );

    /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($meta_query); echo "</pre>";*/
}
```

featured: http://prntscr.com/kno3lk
non-featured: http://prntscr.com/kno3vc

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `orderby` sorts posts by a given parameter. You need the parameter `order` to set the direction.

More details: [Order & Orderby Parameters of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)